# Download Lyrics With Specific Tag From The Internet

Tags: java, android, database, download

I've been slowly learning Java in the last 4 Months. I started my studies and one of my favourite subjects is programming. We've already covered polymorphism and generic data types(and by practicing I'm trying to get the hang of it). As much as that to my Background.

My question now is: How can I download the lyrics from Genius.com? I'd like to develop an Android app that automatically downloads new lyrics as soon as I'm connected to the Internet. Else it should work offline. Of Course I could manually copy the lyrics of my favourite Songs out one after another, but I want to develop an offline lyrics database which Imports the files of the Songs tagged as Rap (i know it will be wasting lots of space but it's for learning purposes). I've found tons of tutorials explaining how to create an Android app but no particualar info covering my question(the one closest would be [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java))

EDIT: Maybe I was a bit too hasty: Following other similar questions I will have to use the datatype URL, right? but how can I Limit the download to only the rap lyrics? How could I get a List that contains all the exact store adresses of the rap lyrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about it. :)
Download file is not a problem, but... lyrics on Genius.com are not just files with texts. They are HTML pages.
In the browser just press F12 or select "View Source" and see what you can get in Java... is there any lyrics? :)
I even did not talk about possibility that there are URL redirection, java scripts, Ajax requests and so, and so...

Comment: Alright. I already did the F12 part but since im not familiar with HTML its kinda confusing... Like you said I found nothing about lyrics there. Can you think of an alternative way of realising my idea without manually copying them? :)

Comment: Sure. Theoretically speaking, It is possible to parse HTML, follow all references in the HTML, find actual link to the lyrics or find exact text there, download it or take the text out...

Comment: But... it is huge amount of work and if Genius.com be changed at some time (and it will be, believe me) all code must be rewritten again. Once in a while I did something like that against one site, just for my needs. It worked for couple month then site was changed and all became useless. But I did not need it anymore at that time. I was lucky :)

Comment: A'ight, thanks. I think I'll give up on it then :) Or maybe pick it up again once I'm a bit more experienced.